# IE 10/11 won't call repeating GET requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

During an AJAX photo upload, the POST request is sent with the photo and returned successfully. However, the server still has some resizing tasks to complete before the image can be displayed. I set a timeout to loop until the image can be found by setting its source to what it will be once the server processes the image.

All other browsers(Chrome/Safari/Firefox) work great by repeating the GET request and eventually find it. IE 10/11 send one GET, returns a 404 and won't send anymore requests.

I've also tried AJAX requests as GETs for the image, same thing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your get request isn't being cached? Try appending a random parameter to the request each get. This will make the browser think you're pulling a different uri and not use the cached response.

E.x. some site.com/source?ignoreme=1526353377

If using jQuery you can set cache: false in your $.ajax call as well. It basically does exactly what explained above for you automatically.

Comment: Awesome! I remember reading that somewhere and it didn't click. Worked perfectly.